# Convert complicated yet simple XML to CSV using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to convert an XML (generated by a source) to CSV using XSLT.

Below is the input XML generated by an external source. I am not sure if this is even a valid xml as the value of Details tag is a big list.

```
<Data>
<Details COLUMNS="Counterparty,Iteration,StartDateTime,Quantity">
ABC,1,23/10/2013 06:00,10
ABC,1,23/10/2013 06:30,12
ABC,1,23/10/2013 07:00,15
ABC,1,23/10/2013 07:30,5
ABC,1,23/10/2013 08:00,180
ABC,1,23/10/2013 08:30,87
ABC,1,23/10/2013 09:00,88
ABC,1,23/10/2013 09:30,56
ABC,1,23/10/2013 10:00,13
ABC,1,24/10/2013 00:00,0
ABC,1,24/10/2013 00:30,8.7
ABC,1,24/10/2013 01:00,100.9
ABC,1,24/10/2013 01:30,1.1
ABC,1,24/10/2013 02:00,2.2
ABC,1,24/10/2013 02:30,3.2
ABC,1,24/10/2013 03:00,20
ABC,1,24/10/2013 03:30,30
</Details>
</Data>
```

I want to create an XSLT that could convert this XML into CSV as below. I looked at numerous links online but wasn't able to create such an XSL transform. Please help!

```
Counterparty,StartDate,StartTime,EndTime,Volume
ABC,23/10/2013,0600,0630,10
ABC,23/10/2013,0630,0700,12
ABC,23/10/2013,0700,0730,15
ABC,23/10/2013,0730,0800,5
ABC,23/10/2013,0800,0830,180
.
.
.
.
ABC,24/10/2013,0300,0330,20
ABC,24/10/2013,0330,0400,30
```

Adding more information based on comments: I need to go inside the element text and manipulate it (add/edit/remove text). I am open to using XSLT 2.0 if it has way to manipulate the text without too much hassle. There is a LF and CR between each line of text. Please let me know the best way. Thanks!

Regards,
Amit

Comment: Well, basically the `Details` element already *is* a CSV file, so all your XSLT needs to do is output the header, and then the contents of that one element, right?

Comment: Yes, as it stands, an empty transform would get you everything but the header (because the default template will select element text).

Comment: Or are you trying to get the XSLT to inspect the data inside the CSV, so that you can manipulate the date column to get more columns in the output than the input, as in the example? If so, I'm not sure XSLT is the right tool for the job, because that's not an XML structure. Why not use a more general-purpose scripting language, such as Perl, Awk, PHP, etc?

Comment: If you do need to look inside the data, rather than just copying it to the output, then the way to do it will depend on whether you are using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. XSLT 2.0 has much stronger facilities for text manipulation. When asking XSLT questions, always say which version you are using.

Comment: Is there already newline feeds between each line of the text in the `Details` tag?

Comment: Thanks for quick and helpful responses. I need to go inside the element text and manipulate it (add/edit/remove text). I am open to using XSLT 2.0 if it has way to manipulate the text without too much hassle. There is a LF and CR between each line of text. Please let me know the best way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following XSLT 2.0 yields the desired output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/Data">
    <xsl:text>Counterparty,StartDate,StartTime,EndTime,Volume&#10;</xsl:text>

    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(Details/text(), '[&#10;&#13;]')">

      <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\s*([^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+) +([0-9]+):([0-9]+),([0-9\.]+)">

        <xsl:matching-substring>
          <xsl:variable name="prefix" select="regex-group(1)"/>
          <xsl:variable name="hours" select="regex-group(2)"/>
          <xsl:variable name="minutes" select="regex-group(3)"/>
          <xsl:variable name="suffix" select="regex-group(4)"/>

          <xsl:variable name="startTime" select="number($hours) * 60 + number($minutes)"/>
          <xsl:variable name="endTime" select="$startTime + 30"/>
          <xsl:variable name="endHours" select="format-number($endTime div 60, '00')"/>
          <xsl:variable name="endMinutes" select="format-number($endTime mod 60, '00')"/>

          <xsl:value-of select="concat($prefix, ',', $hours, $minutes, ',', $endHours, $endMinutes, ',', $suffix)"/><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>          
        </xsl:matching-substring>

      </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Notes:

- The XSLT makes some assumptions about the contents of the columns of the input file and their seperators. The `regex` expression may have to be changed if the example provided in the question does not represent production data well.
- The conversion should work with all input files having line seperators newline and/or linebreak or any combination thereof. I haven't tried this, though.
- The XSLT makes some assumptions about how the end time is derived (+ 30 minutes). This may have to changed.